# Opensips 2.1 and kamailio difference and better to choose which one

Tags: kamailio, opensips

I want to know opensips 2.1 or kamailio is better,how differentiate its performance.how can i choose,major difference between two,which one i have to choose for routing in softswiching

Comment: I think this is a bit too broad, such Resources are typically found using a search engine. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Comment: http://www.voip-info.org/boards/view/topic/16417 refer this